# Is there a central FreePascal/Lazarus Component repository?

Tags: repository, components, lazarus, freepascal

I'm looking to find something like [Torry](http://torry.net) but instead of being Delphi centric, it should be Lazarus centric.

I'm aware of the Source Forge Project [Code and Component Repository](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/) but I'm looking for something with more span and a bit more searching features.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893469/could-free-pascal-benefit-of-something-like-apache-maven

Comment: Thanks @mjustin, that looks quite inspiring !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There is this page in the Lazarus wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Components_and_Code_examples) which probably has most of Lazarus components (it includes some components not found in CCR). Its pretty well searchable. There are also the forums and the mailing list where components are announced (and usually are mentioned in the above wiki page).

Lazarus isn't as popular as Delphi or other solutions, so its not that easy to find stuff for it :-/. Although porting components from Delphi isn't a very hard process - many components available for Lazarus were originally Delphi components.

Comment: Moreover, many of the things needed for porting to FPC also need to be done for porting to non 32-bit Windows Delphi too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a component web site :
http://lazarus-components.org

I have seen that we can create lazarus repositories, but there is poor doc about that.

Comment: It's another site with some data. Oddly enough it's a bit cluttered and not that well done. Maybe because it's under some CMS app.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Lazarus IDE have an Online Package Manager function.

IDE Menu: Package > Online Package Manager.

This open a window with a pretty good list of packages that that be downloaded and installed with a couple of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I use lazarus BigIDE from http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon
full LCL from more source

Comment: This is not a searchable repository of components like the torry.net site, hence my down-vote